# sudo subl - como abrir o sublime 3 pelo terminal no Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, sublime-text, editor-de-texto

Realizei a instalação do Sublime Text 3 no Ubuntu 17.10. 
Consigo abrir o Sublime utilizando o comando **subl** no terminal. Porém não funciona abrir como **sudo**, ao utilizar o comando nada acontece.

Porém funciona rodar os comandos **sudo subl -h** para acessar o help do sublime e **sudo subl -v** para ver a versão.

Abaixo o conteúdo do arquivo sublime_text.desktop

```
--------------------------------------------------------

rodolfo@rodolfo-ntb:/usr/share/applications$ cat sublime_text.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Sublime Text
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Sophisticated text editor for code, markup and prose
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text %F
Terminal=false
MimeType=text/plain;
Icon=sublime-text
Categories=TextEditor;Development;
StartupNotify=true
Actions=Window;Document;

[Desktop Action Window]
Name=New Window
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text -n
OnlyShowIn=Unity;

[Desktop Action Document]
Name=New File
Exec=/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --command new_file
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
rodolfo@rodolfo-ntb:/usr/share/applications$
```

---

Comment: Ao usar `sudo -H ./sublime_text` funciona perfeitamente aqui. Em geral, não é recomendado abrir programas que salvam dados no diretorio do usuario apenas como 'sudo', sem o '-H'.

Comment: Aqui não funciona dessa forma, no meu caso está no diretório /opt/sublime_text

Answer (score 0):

Eu recebi ajuda em um grupo no Telegram, e isto não é um bug. O Ubuntu 17.10 está utilizando Wayland, e o Wayland não permite a execução de programas como sudo. Antes de iniciar a sessão com o usuário eu troquei para iniciar o Ubuntu com Xorg e agora está funcionando o comando sudo subl.